European? heist movie where a guy breaks tempered glass by hitting the right place
I saw this movie as a kid in the 80's, on TV, dubbed in Russian, can't tell the original language.
It looked like a 60's or 70's movie, probably French or Italian.
The thing the protagonist tried to steal was kept in a tempered glass box. He said to his partner in crime that tempered glass was impossible to break unless you know where exactly to hit.
He hit the box with a mallet several times, to no avail, then found the "right point" and struck it lightly, and the box shattered to pieces.

Don't you remember anything else about the movie? Was it maybe a comedy? What were they trying to steal, a single object? Do you remember what was it?

@Pesetas74: unfortunately, no. I just remember I spent a couple of days trying to break my aunt's glass table "accidentally" dropping the fork on it.

Well, then this is kind of a looong shot, but your description got me thinking about the italian movie "Operazione San Gennaro" aka "The Treasure of San Gennaro" IMDB Here is a scene immediately preceding the one I'm thinking about Scene - couldn't find that one on youtube

@Pesetas74: that's it, here, from 1:14:00: http://tfilm.me/23337-operaciya-svyatoy-yanuariy.html (in Russian). Please post it as an answer.

any idea about language?

The film you are looking for is the classic and very funny Italian comedy "Operazione San Gennaro" (1966 - aka "The Treasure of San Gennaro) by the director Dino Risi, especially acclaimed for his '60s comedies ("Il Sorpasso" above all), starring Nino Manfredi, Totò (in a small but very significative role) and Senta Berger among others.

Here is a short synopsis taken from Wikipedia:

In Italy in the Sixties, a gang of American thieves arrive in Naples to steal the famous Treasure of San Gennaro. However the Americans do not know how to move in the picturesque town. For the customs of the natives are too weird and incomprehensible to them. So the two men and the girl (the gang members) go to a prison, following the advice of a friend. There he would find the man who would have done in their case. It is a certain Don Vincenzo, a very famous in the city for his theft. He however, since it is known by everyone there, is treated in the prison as a gentleman by the guards with all possible facilities. The Americans, when they see this type of treatment, impossible in a country like them, remain quite stunned. Don Vincenzo warmly received them and advises them to go to Naples to look for a certain Armandino Girasole, said "Dudù". He, a young thief by profession, would help them steal the treasure of San Gennaro, fortunately not mentioned by the Americans to Don Vincenzo. The Americans, keeping secret the purpose of theft, meet Dudù and agree with him.

Here is the scene in which the gang manages to access San Gennaro's crypt in order to steal the treasure that briefly anticipates the one the OP was referring to:




After many unsuccessful attempts, Dudù manages to break the reinforced glass by unintentionally throwing his not working golden lighter against the glass in an act of frustration.   

